# How to configure sql server database in kapow design studio with integrated security?

Tags: sql-server, kapow

I'm trying to configure and create connection for sql server database using integrated security not using username and password in my kapow design studio.

But there is option in kapow design studio to enable integrated security for sql server.

Comment: Very confusing question. `But there is option in kapow design studio to enable integrated security for sql server.`  So, I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I didn't find any such option, could you please help me that where this option is ?

Comment: So you're asking if there is an option? It looks like you are making a statement that there is an option. Not knowing kapow, I'm sorry I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Databases in Design Studio (DS) can be configured in two ways. A database is either configured manually as a Local Database in every DS, or they are configured in the Management Console (MC), and pushed automatically to DS.

Local databases do not support integrated security. As per the documentation, [integrated security](https://docshield.kofax.com/Kapow/en_US/100_oe702eebym/10.3/help/kap_help/mgmtconsole/c_addnewdatabasetype.html?h=integrated%20security) is supported if you push the database settings from MC to DS.

**Additional details**
It makes a lot of sense to use integrated security for the MC and log database, and potentially for the robot data database in production. I prefer not to use integrated security for DS, since this means that every developer needs a login on SQL Server. If you use a SQL Server authentication, all developers can share the same credentials (and they don't need to know them).
If you decide to use integrated security for developers in DS, you have to decide if they should use the same schema or share one. If they have their own schema, they will not be able to see their data in MC (as MC will look at its own schema), so you have to give them access to SQL Server Management Studio or another tool.